# Image and String in HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, http, servlets, mime-types

I have String data and image files 
to send in an `HttpServletResponse`. How 
can this be done? i know how to send 
String and image separately. 
Couldn't see a MIME format to send both.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, as a single HTTP response can only send a single file. However, you can embed an image using the [`data:` URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) by creating an image similar to:

```
<img src = "data:image/png;base64,<data>" />
```

where `<data>` is the image encoded as base-64.

Of course, you can always store the image and serve it in a separate request initiated by the browser when it comes across your image tag, especially for large images.